# Installing Chrome onto Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation

When trying to install Chrome onto my AWS Ubuntu instance, I ran the following command:

```
sudo curl -sS -o - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add
```

And got: This command can only be used by root

Answer (score 1):

Put `sudo` in front of `apt-key`, since that's the command that needs root. You also need `-` as the filename for `apt-key add`:

```
curl -sS -o - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```